# JavaScript list button. Need list to end

Tags: javascript, list, button, items

I have made a list application using JavaScript. I want to be able to put in items and when I click the button grab the items or tasks randomly. I got it to grab the tasks randomly, but want it to end once its gone through the items added. Right now it just keeps randomly cycling through the list endlessly. What am I missing?

Here's the code:

```js
var taskList = [];

var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var listTasks = function() {
  textList = "";
  for (var i in taskList) {
    textList += taskList[i] + "\n";
  }
  $("task_list").value = textList;
}

var addTask = function() {
  taskList[taskList.length] = $("new_task").value;
  $("new_task").value = "";
  $("new_task").focus();
  listTasks();
}

var showNextTask = function() {
  if (taskList.length == 0) {
    alert("No tasks in the list");
    $("next_task").value = "";
  } else {
    $("next_task").value = taskList[Math.floor(Math.random() * taskList.length)];
    taskList.shift(Math.value());
  }

  if (taskList.length == 0) {
    alert("No tasks in the list");
    $("next_task").value = "";
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  $("add_task").onclick = addTask;
  $("show_next_task").onclick = showNextTask;
  $("new_task").focus();
}
```

Comment: Do not do this, it is confusing... `const $ = id => document.getElementById(id)` ...for many reasons. Firstly, someone might think it's a jQuery call. Secondly, you could use `querySelector` instead.

Comment: Remove the task from `tasklist` when you grab it.

Comment: There's no such thing as `Math.value()`. What is `taskList.shift(Math.value());` supposed to be doing?